# Reading metadata from online mp3-file

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

I would like to read the mp3 `bitrate` of an online MP3 file, f.e. [this one](http://www.ntonyx.com/mp3files/Morning_Flower_%28Fragment%29.mp3), preferrably without downloading it in its entirety.

I've been able to find out that ffmpeg allows one to do this, f.e. like so:

```
ffmpeg -i http://physics.ujep.cz/~mmaly/mp3/Mozart/Mass_in_C_Minor_New_by_Levin/sbory_vyssi_kvalita/01_Kyrie.mp3
```

but I wasn't able to find a portable way to do this. (pyffmpeg requires a C compiler as well as Cython and keeps throwing new error messages at me every time I resolve one)

If anyone has any tips/links/knows where to get further ideas, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out - if you have the length of the track - you can estimate the bitrate like so:

```
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)

meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders('Content-Length')[0])

estimated_bitrate = file_size/length_secs/1000*8
```

for checking after the fact I use mutagen

Answer (score 1):

I think the id3 tag is stored at the beginning of an mp3 file, you'd likely want to first learn the mp3 fileformat so you know how the data is stored. Then you'd begin downloading the file, and close the connection when you have enough data to read the bitrate.

Here's a link to the fileformat spec: http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

You'll just need to download the first 30 bits or so, and then parse it out. Not too hard.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359279/read-id3-tags-without-downloading-the-whole-file/5359297#5359297) there are various locations where the metadata might be stored ... with the web so wildly diversified as well as there not being one standard for storing this information, and seeing how ffmpeg already does this so well, I'd rather hand over control to a specialised piece of code that does this for me, instead of having to reinvent the wheel.